# Incoherent results on local host vs dev and production servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following method

```
  if request.subdomains.empty?
    rurl = 'www.' + request.host  
  else
    rurl = request.host  
  end
  clean_host = rurl.chomp("/")
Rails.logger.info clean_host
  @site = Site.where('host = ?', clean_host.to_s).first
Rails.logger.info @site.inspect
```

runs as designed on servers.  On localhost, a dummy `Site` object was created to handle a request form a test. Verifying via the console:

```
irb(main):001:0> clean_host = "www.example.com"
=> "www.example.com"
irb(main):002:0> @site = Site.where('host = ?', clean_host.to_s).first
  Site Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "sites".* FROM "sites" WHERE (host = 'www.example.com') ORDER BY "sites"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Site id: 7, shop_id: 1, host: "www.example.com", name: "localhost", host_short: nil, logo: nil, controller: "localhost", layout: "application", created_at: "2021-06-01 11:09:10.261480000 +0200", updated_at: "2021-06-01 11:09:10.261480000 +0200">
```

When this method is executed on localhost, via a test

```
sign_in @user_shop
get user_acqs_path
```

test.log shows a thoroughly unexpected result.  While the testing issues the request with a 'www.example.com' host, it is not being processed by the controller action.

```
www.example.com

Site Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "sites".* FROM "sites" WHERE (host = 'www.example.com') ORDER BY "sites"."id" ASC LIMIT $1[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]
[36mCACHE Site Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "sites".* FROM "sites" WHERE (host = 'www.example.com') ORDER BY "sites"."id" ASC LIMIT $1[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]

nil
```

the test has a setup block

```
 setup do
    @user = users(:end_consumer_phone)
    @site = sites(:thirty_one)
 end
```

with the following fixture

```
thirty_one:
  id: 31
  shop_id: 31
  host: "example.com"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `test` and `development` are not the same environment. In test you should set up this dummy site in the testing suite e.g. (in rspec) `let!(:dummy_site) {Site.find_or_create_by(host: "www.example.com", name: "localhost")}`

Comment: I am using minitest with a setup block with  `@site = sites(:dummy)`  Swapped out for `@site = Site.find_or_create_by(host: "www.example.com" name: "localhost")` returning the same results as above...

Comment: You need to actually create the `Site` is you are going to query the database for it.

Comment: Isn't that the role of the fixture? question amended to show it.

Comment: my bad. I tripped myself up in testing the request without the 'www' with the method to populate the subdomain agianst the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

```
rurl = 'www.' + request.host
```

is setting  the request, which, from the test helper

```
def setup
  host! 'example.com'
end
```

leads to a different string to compare againt the fixture

```
host: "example.com"
```

Fixture amended to

```
host: "www.example.com"
```

processes accordingly. *lesson: be wary of your fixtures*